# How to connect to pgbouncer from asyncpg library?

Tags: python, postgresql, pgbouncer, asyncpg

I have implemented pgbouncer with asyncpg and also asyncpg native pool implementation. Though i'm able to send many concurrent request through pgbouncer but my p95  is close to 8sec for 1000 concurrent request where as with asyncpg native pool implementation, the p95 is just above 1.5sec.

Why is there so much performance difference? Is this the correct way to connect to pgbouncer from asyncpg?

Code Example:

1. With asyncpg and pgbouncer:

```py
pgbouncer_creds = {
   "user": "myuser",
   "password": "password",
   "host": "localhost",
   "port": "16432",
   "database": "db1"
}

async def test():
   async def db():
       start = time.time()
       connection = await asyncpg.connect(**pgbouncer_creds)
       await connection.fetchrow("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id=$1;", "5db03111822547b59c3edaa324e0f829")
       await connection.close()
       end = time.time()
       times.append((end - start))

   tasks = [db() for _ in range(1000)]
   await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
   loop.run_until_complete(test())
   loop.close()
```

2. Native asyncp pool implementation

```py
creds = {
    "user": "myuser",
    "password": "password",
    "host": "*.*.*.*",
    "port": "5432",
    "database": "db1"
}
async def test():
    pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(**creds, max_size=100, min_size=100)
    async def db():
        start = time.time()
        async with pool.acquire() as connection:
            await connection.fetchrow("SELECT * FROM test WHERE id=$1;", "5db03111822547b59c3edaa324e0f829")
        end = time.time()
        times.append((end - start))
    tasks = [db() for _ in range(1000)]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(test())
    loop.close()
```

#### pgbouncer.ini file:

```
[databases]
db1 = host=*.*.*.* dbname=db1
[pgbouncer]
listen_addr = *
listen_port = 16432
auth_type = plain
auth_file = userlist.txt
default_pool_size = 100
max_db_connections = 200
max_client_conn = 10000
max_user_connections = 200
pool_mode = session
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be slower?  asyncpg's connection pooler is coded specifically for it, of course it is faster for the exact thing it was built for then some general purpose tool is.

Comment: Isn't pgbouncer built for the same purpose?  I don't see difference in pgbouncer and asyncpg's connection pooler. Both keep pool of active connection for client use.

Comment: pgbouncer is a connection pooler, but is not written specifically for asyncpg, nor does it run embedded in the same process as python itself.  Every interaction with pgbouncer involves network/IPC overhead, and many of them also involve establishing, authenticating, and taking down a connection.  (That connection is not to PostgreSQL, but still it isn't free)

Comment: Cool thanks for the explanation. If you can write down the explanation as answer that would be helpful.